# How do I erase an encrypted TimeMachine drive on Mountain Lion if I've forgotten the password?

Tags: macos, time-machine, disk-utility, filevault, encryption

My question is similar to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26259/lost-password-on-mac-os-extended-journaled-encrypted-drive-want-to-reformat). I have a USB drive that contains an old encrypted backup. I don't remember the password and don't care about loosing the backup - I just want to be able to use the drive. When I select the volume on the left, I only see two tabs: "First Aid" and "Partition". I don't see an "Erase" tab.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found the answer [here](http://www.g8production.com/post/29614120476/os-x-mountain-lion-and-disk-encryption-failed-how-to). Basically, from the terminal, type:

```
sudo diskutil cs list
```

You'll get a list of your drives and a bunch of related info. Look for the one you want to format and grab its Logical Volume Group's UUID. It should look something like this:

```
Logical Volume Group XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Then erase the drive by executing the command:

```
sudo diskutil cs delete XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Now you should be able to see the drive and format it using Disk Utility.