# Deleting a hard drive protected by password with Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: hard-drive, password, macos

I recently changed my hard drive for a SSD device. The removed storage device can be used as an external drive, via USB. I want to delete everything on this HD, but it is asking me for a password when I plug it in the Mac. I forgot the password.

I tried every password I have in mind, but it didn't work. I want to force format of the hard drive, but neither Disk Utility nor Terminal commands works (Apple may have locked these functions).

I tried the procedures described in [this topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26259/lost-password-on-mac-os-extended-journaled-encrypted-drive-want-to-reformat/186595?noredirect=1#comment220345_186595), without any success.

With Mac OS Yosemite 10.10, the following message is displayed in Terminal:

```
Usage: diskutil coreStorage delete lvgUUID|lvgName

Delete a CoreStorage logical volume group. All logical volumes will be removed.
Ownership of the affected disks is required.
```

Is there a way to overpass this with Mac OS X?

Comment: Was your HD encypted with something like FileVault? You can boot to recovery HD (Command+R on startup) and either reinstall OS X, or go to disk utility and erase the only HD partition. If failed, use either Internet Recovery or boot from recovery on a USB

Comment: Since you recently changed it, how were you able to use it before ?

Answer (score 2):

If a partition was encrypted with `FileVault`, and you have forgotten your password, you need to boot into the Recovery Partition to format the partition / drive. (Hold down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> during startup to get there.)  From there, you can use Disk Utility to erase the encrypted partition.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wipe the disks. Wipefs or even parted could be used, or you could just write zeroes to the drive using dd.

The osx tools have some protection against deleting partitions in case of a corestorage being there.